# textarea counts characters length wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

When I typed the first character in textarea it still shows 0 and count gets 1 for the second character. Not sure why? I'm using keydown event for this.

```
$(".textArea").keydown(updateCount());

function updateCount() {
    count = $(".textArea").val().length;
    this.$countDiv.text(count + " of 240");
};
```

Comment: what about if use keyup event? use keyup event

Comment: keydown counts when you're pressing the key. try keyup instead!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `input` event.  This will cover all changes to the textbox value, including copy & paste etc. (even with the mouse)...

```js
$("#text").on("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    count = $("#text").val().length;
    $("#count").text(count + " of 240");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="count"></div>
```

There were also some other issues, like the fact that you executed the `updateCount` function, rather than assigned it to the event handler (you had `()` after the function name.  If you remove that then it becomes a reference to the function, rather than executes it there and then).

I also used an id for the textarea element, rather than a class, but that's just me - if a class works in your scenario then it's fine.

Comment: Perfect answer, its simple and does what the op wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass function to `$.keydown`, not a result of execution:

```
$(".textArea").keydown(updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    count = $('.textArea').val().length;
    this.$countDiv.text(count + ' of 240');
}
```

When you pass result of execution, it must be executed before `keydown` processing. Because `keydown` depends to result of execution of `updateCount`, so `updateCount` is always executed before `keydown`, so you got length of string state before `keydown`.

Comment: keydown fires before the key is pressed and that would resolve in the wrong value of `count`

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you’re trying to implement, the keydown event isn’t sufficient for it. You’d have to use the `keyup` event. At that point the key press is complete.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".textArea").on('keydown', function(event) {
     updateCount();
 });

function updateCount() {
var count = $(".textArea").val().length;
console.log("count",count);
}
```

Comment: You should always aim to leave an explanation about what you have changed and why

Answer (score -1):

fire event on all 3 change keyup paste. It will also handle if someone tries to paste in text box
like below

```
$('.textArea').on('change keyup paste', updateCount());
```